# Qt Quick image not showing

Tags: c++, image, qt, user-interface

When I try to add an image to the template of new qt quick project, it compiles and shows the window, but only the edit text and the rectangle only shows.

```
import QtQuick 2.6

Rectangle {
   property alias mouseArea: mouseArea
   property alias textEdit: textEdit

   width: 360
   height: 360

   MouseArea {
    id: mouseArea
    anchors.fill: parent
   }

   TextEdit {
    id: textEdit
    text: qsTr("Enter some text...")
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.topMargin: 20
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: -10
        color: "transparent"
        border.width: 1
    }
   }
   Image {
    id: image
    x: 207
    y: 235
    width: 100
    height: 100
    source: "../../QtIcon.png"
   }
```

}

Comment: Solved by using qrc resource editor and added the image :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use image in file system by adding file:// infront.
Example: source: "file://C:/test.png"

Comment: Thanks, this could be a second option. But it is solved using the resource editor.